# Mysql - Select rooms where have all the dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

Hi there I have the availability of rooms in a table like this:

```
room_id |          date       
   1    | 2018-06-09 00:00:00 
   1    | 2018-06-10 00:00:00 
   1    | 2018-06-11 00:00:00 
   2    | 2018-06-09 00:00:00 
   2    | 2018-06-11 00:00:00 
   3    | 2018-06-09 00:00:00 
   4    | 2018-06-07 00:00:00 
...
```

I send an array of dates and I want to get if any room have availability for all days:

```
SELECT rtd.room_id, CASE WHEN Count(rtd.room_id) < 2 THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END
FROM room_type_day as rtd
WHERE 
rtd.date IN ('2018-06-09 00:00:00', '2018-06-10 00:00:00', '2018-06-11 00:00:00')
GROUP BY rtd.room_type_id
```

But this return me:

```
1  | yes
2  | yes
3  | yes
4  | no
```

How can I find the rooms that are available all the days?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

If I add HAVING(COUNT DISTINCT rtd.date) = 3" before "group by", I get this error:
[image]

**EDIT**

This works for me:

```
SELECT `room_id`
FROM `room_type_day`
WHERE `date` IN ('2018-06-09', '2018-06-10', '2018-06-11')
GROUP BY `room_id`
HAVING COUNT(`room_id`) = 3;
```

**But how can I modify this query if one or more rooms is available, return "yes" and if no one, return "no"?**

Thak you

Comment: Hint: HAVING clause.

Comment: Add `HAVING(COUNT DISTINCT rtd.date) = 3`

Comment: Or another way of thinking about it... can you find rooms that aren't available for any of the days? (TB's solution could be excessively tedious)

Comment: please can you write all the sql? If I write add "HAVING(COUNT DISTINCT rtd.date) = 3" before "group by" y get error of syntax

Comment: the HAVING clause will remove those rooms in which the answer is 'No'.

Comment: investigate having. don't write it before the group, write it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

**Query**

```
SELECT `room_id`
FROM `room_type_day`
WHERE `date` IN ('2018-06-09', '2018-06-10', '2018-06-11')
GROUP BY `room_id`
HAVING COUNT(`room_id`) = 3;
```

**[Find SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bef03/1)**

Comment: This will remove the rooms in which the answer is 'No' and the distinct clause should be there as well

Comment: @Dataichou : Only room_id `1` is available for all the 3 days.

Comment: I agree this is a valid answer. I would  add DISTINCT only because i don't know whether there could be duplicates. Also I am trying to follow his/her initial expected output format

Comment: Thank you @Wanderer , this works for me. But how can I modify this query to do if one or more rooms is available, return "yes" and if no one return "no"?

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by a column which is not found in the table.

```
SELECT 
   A.room_id, 
   IF(A.count=A.count_in_range,'Yes','No') status
FROM 
(SELECT 
   room_id, 
   COUNT(*) count, 
   SUM(IF(date IN ('2018-06-09 00:00:00', '2018-06-10 00:00:00', 
                   '2018-06-11 00:00:00'),1,0)) count_in_range
FROM room_type_day
GROUP BY room_id) A;
```

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a8f1/7).

Answer (score 0):

try it like this and make sure that the days_= amount of days in your 'IN' statement

```
    SELECT room_id, CASE WHEN days_=3 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) as availability
    FROM
    (
      SELECT rtd.room_id, Count(distinct rtd.room_id)  as days_
      FROM room_type_day as rtd
      WHERE rtd.date IN ('2018-06-09 00:00:00', '2018-06-10 00:00:00', '2018-06-11 00:00:00')
      GROUP BY rtd.room_type_id
     ) as sub
```